# Termination of Bellman-Ford algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms

Good day,

I am currently going over some problems from my optimisation class and I can not seem to figure this one out.

> Assume that in the Shortest Path Problem, Bellman-Ford terminates but some vertices still remain unchanged i.e. $y_v=\infty$ for some $v\in V$
>
> Show that $\exists  \ X\subset V $ such that $c(uv)=\infty \ \forall \ uv \in A, \ u \in X, \ v\in V\setminus X $ (there is a subset $X$ such that the cost of each edge with one vertex in $X$ and one outside of it is $\infty$).

I am not really sure how to get started on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what might help you is the following:

The Bellman-Ford algorithm computes one-to-all shortest paths by repeated relaxation. If at the end of the algorithm some vertices still have value $\infty$, then those vertices must be in a different connected component than the starting vertex $a$. Otherwise they would have been reached over some path starting from $a$ and then they wouldn't have value $\infty$ anymore.

Now to solve this you have to somehow define your set $X$. I suggest you try with $X = \{ v \in V \text{ such that v has value } \infty \text{ when Bellman-Ford has terminated} \}$.

(The cost of an edge between to vertices $u, v$ is considered $\infty$ if in the original graph there is no such edge. At least that's what I assume. The transformation from no edge to an edge with value $\infty$ is made for Bellman-Ford to operate on the graph.)

Comment: So, I defined a set X as you said and this would give that 

$V \setminus X = \{ v \in V \text{ such that v has value } < \infty \text{ when Bellman-Ford has terminated} \}$

Then I can assume, for the sake of a contradiction, that for some $a \in X$ $c(av)< \infty$. I am not quite sure what else I can do but this already feels like a step in the wrong direction.

Comment: Oh I see that I made a mistake. It makes more sense to actually define X = {v∈V such that v has NOT value ∞ when Bellman-Ford has terminated}. If we do it like this then now you can assume for a contradiction that for some $a \in X$ and some $v \in V-X$ we have $c(av) < \infty$. But then $v$ cannot have value $\infty$ after Bellman-Ford has terminated, because $a$ does not have value $\infty$ and $c(av) < \infty$. This is a contradiction with $v$ being in $V - X$.

Comment: Yes, that definition of $X$ makes much more sense. Thank you for your input.